# regex (java) match numbers equal or greater than 20, incremented by 5, no leading zeros allowed

Tags: java, regex, repeat, upperbound, number-sequence

I am a new user, so excuse if this question should be answered in it's original post:
[regex match numbers greater or equal than 20, by increments of 5, range 20 to 999](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648152/regex-match-numbers-greater-or-equal-than-20-by-increments-of-5-range-20-to-99)

Neverteless, here is the current question:

- Match all numbers equal or greater then 20 (no upper limit)
- Increments of 5
- No decimal point
- Leading zeros shouldn't be allowed

With [stackoverflow user YMI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2642059/YMI) response on another post:

```
(\d{2}|[2-9])[05]
```

and [user nhahtdh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33648407/2642059)

```
^([2-9]|[1-9]\d)[05]$
```

However I would like to explorer the option of not having upper limit and the leading zeros not being allowed also.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very similar to [`nhahtdh`'s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33648407/2642059) but note the `\d+` rather than a `\d` which places no upper limit on the number of characters.

You'll want a regex like this:

```
\b((?:[23456789]|[123456789]\d+)[05])\b
```

[[Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/yR4iS7/2)]

To give a quick explanation of what's happening here:

- `\b` matches a boundary, like a white-space or a symbol so the `\b`s will find complete words from the text
- Next we give two options for the word prefix, it can be a single number 2 or greater: `[23456789]`
- Or it can be 2 or more numbers that are not led by a 0: `[123456789]\d+`
- For our suffix we require it to be a multiple of 5: `[05]`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

Incidentally you can match numbers that meet your other criteria but also posses leading 0s by simply consuming the 0s and then matching the number, note the addition of `0*` which will match any number of leading 0s:

```
\b0*((?:[23456789]|\d{2,})[05])\b
```